# Should I bring a variable through parameters or get it with global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, global-variables

Is it better to bring along a variable through function parameters or get it with global? Am just wondering what's the most efficient. To have an extra parameter in all my functions or get the variable with global where it's needed.

```
a = "example"

def b(c):
    d(c)

def d(e):
    f(e)

def f(g):
    print(g)

b(a)
```

Versus:

```
a = "example"

def b(c):
   d(c)

def d(e):
   f(e)

def f(g):
   global a
   print(a)

b(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it around from function to function.

Not only will code be more easy to understand and follow but, you also get the added benefit of Python loading values passed locally (via the `LOAD_FAST` byte code) much faster than it does when it looks them up globally (`LOAD_GLOBAL` byte code).

Comment: Okay :) Thank you.